# Why is distance function subanalytic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having trouble understanding Edward Bierstone and Pierre D. Milman's argument showing that the distance function is subanalytic, specifically "Remarks 3.11" in "[Semianalytic and subanalytic sets](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02699126)" Publications Mathématiques de l'Institut des Hautes Études Scientifiques, 67, 5-42 (1988), [MR972342](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=972342), [Zbl 0674.32002](https://zbmath.org/0674.32002). Below is a direct copy of "Remarks 3.11".

> *Remarks* **3.11.** — Let $X$ be a subanalytic subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then the distance function $d(x,X) = \min_{z\in \overline{X}}|x-z|$ is subanalytic: We can assume that $X$ is relatively compact. Let $A = \{(x,z,y)\in \mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}:\, z\in \overline{X},\, y\geq |x-z|\}$. Then $A$ is subanalytic. Let $\pi$ denote the projection $\pi(x,z,y) = (x,y)$. Then, $\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}:\, y\geq d(x,X)\} = \pi(A)$ is subanalytic, and the assertion follows from the theorem of the complement.

The theorem cited, whose proof is given just before the remarks, is the following one:

> *Theorem* **3.10** (Theorem of the complement). Let $M$ be a real analytic manifold and let $X$ be a subanalytic subset of $M$. Then $M-X$ is subanalytic.

It's my understanding that we want to show that the graph of the distance function is a subanalytic set in $\mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}$. Specifically, we want to show that $\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}:\, y= d(x,X)\}$ is subanalytic in $\mathbf{R}^n \times \mathbf{R}$. And to show that we need to show there exists some semianalytic set $A$ and projection $\pi$ such that $\pi(A) = \{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}:\, y= d(x,X)\}$.

I'm just confused as to what they are doing. How are they able to just say "A is subanalytic"? Is it that clear that it is? And again they aren't really talking about the graph of the distance function, but instead *"the graph and things above it"*. Any advice in understanding this proof would be greatly appreciated.

*Edits*. It's my understanding that somehow $A$ is a semianalytic set and therefore trivially subanalytic. However, I'm unable to "describe" it by real analytic functions.
 Furthermore, I think I understand how they use the theorem of the complement. We have that $\pi(A)$ is subanalytic and the interior of any subanalytic set is subanalytic. Hence, let $B$ denote the interior of $\pi(A)$. Therefore, $\pi(A) - B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^n \times \mathbf{R}:\, y = d(x,X)\}$ is subanalytic. I'm just stuck showing that $A$ is semianalytic and consequently subanalytic.

Comment: FYI, I've removed the "school math" analytic-geometry tag.

Comment: I don't think $A$ is necessarily semi-analytic unless $X$ is, but the additional condition that $y\geq |x-z|$ certainly is of semi-analytic (in fact, semi-algebraic) nature, for it is equivalent to $y\geq 0$ and $y^2\geq (x-z)^2$. I am anxious posting this an answer since it's been ages since I've spent some time with those notions, but I do hope it's useful.

Comment: I was unware you can take intersections when describing a set, but that makes a lot of sense. For some reason, I was only considering unions.